# maps flashing on dynamic div loading

Tags: jquery, google-maps

i have a div which i fill dynamically with the .load() method.
I have a function to display a google map in this div on a click of a link in my menu.

```
function ShowGmap() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.905, 12.710);
    var mapOptions = {
      center: myLatlng,
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mb"),
        mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: map,
  title:"----"
```

mb is the ID of the div I fill everytime. What i want is that each button on my menu will fill this div with different content.
 The problem is: when I click on a second button to change the content of that div, the map flash( sometimes it keep beeing drawed on the div like a background ) for a second. I am not sure if this is a cache problem.
This is the code for the click action on the home button

```
$("#bt_home").click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    click_btdove=false; //this make the button clickable only once
     $("#mb").removeAttr('style');
     $('#mb').load('main_page.html #home');
```

the removeAttr is needed because the div has a grey background after the loading of the map (checked with 'inspect element' on chrome.

Thanks for the help.

edit:
this is a pic of what i mean: [img of the problem](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/19/problemld.png/)

edit #2 this is my project: check out what happened when u click on " dove siamo " button

Comment: Plz confirm which div have the background #mb or #home?

Comment: the #mb div has the grey background. in the #home div there is only the text to show in the #mb when the home button is clicked.

Comment: demo has an invalid API key so nothing loads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this one:

```
 $("#bt_home").click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     click_btdove=false; //this make the button clickable only once
     $("#mb").css({"background":"none"}); // <-----add this to remove the background color
     $('#mb').load('main_page.html #home');
 });
```

As i see your code tries to prevent the default behavior of the link but you have not passed that in the function.

see this if helps.

Comment: okay one question why do you want to remove that attr? if you remove that attribute your map will get outside of that div and will be placed to the top left corner because your `#mb` has a attribute position of relative that is holding within this div.

Comment: instead why don't your try to set background to none if you don't want background color. see the updated answer.

Comment: this fix the problem! But I want that the text in the homepage has a grey-ish background, how can i still do this?

Comment: you have two ways first find this css class `.main_box` and remove the background property in it or second `$("#mb").css({"background":"none"});` use this just after doc ready handler.

Comment: I dont want to remove the background. I still want that the #mb div has ALWAYS that grey fading background on it.